# Pure Components in React Native using Expo

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-native, memory, expo

I started to work with React Native using Expo and I am trying to figure out what the best practices are. Due to my previous experience, I would like to avoid performance issues before they going to be difficult to handle. I've read some articles about Pure Components which seem to help to improve the performance. My question is whether Pure Components are compatible with the expo or if it even has something to do with Expo? I couldn't find any relevant information about it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure components has nothing to do with Expo. They are part of the React fundamentals.

It is impossible to teach you through a comment here the react lifecycles and performance optimizations so my best advises to you are:

- Read a little bit about the react life cycles and understand when component gets rendered.
- Use functional component and hooks as they will make your life much easier and it is the "modern" way to use react.
- For performance improvement read a little bit about the RN bridge and learn "useMemo", "React.memo", "useCallback". The best way for me to get deeper understaning after reading documentation was watching YouTube videos. I really recommend the ["Web Dev Simplified"](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFbNIlppjAuEX4znoulh0Cw) channel.